# How do I select a specific child of a <select> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm creating a map in which clicking on different cities will pull up different menus, and highlight the selected city. A `<select>` box is also available for the mobile version of the site since the map is too small. The map is functioning correctly except that when the user uses the `<select>` box, the highlight does not change to the selected city. The console is throwing this error:

```
map.js:41 Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[cityIndex].toggleClass is not a function
at HTMLSelectElement.changeCity (map.js:41:31)
at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:43064)
at v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:41048)
```

because of this line of code:

```
$('g')[cityIndex].toggleClass('is-checked');
```

Where `g` is the SVG element being acted upon, `cityIndex` is the index of the city in the array that stores the cities, and `.is-checked` is the class that changes the appearance of the city in the SVG.

Comment: The `selectedIndex` property of the `<select>` should give the index of the selected `<option>`.

Comment: Thanks @ITgoldman, that helped, but now I've got a new problem. I've updated the description if you have time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @Twisty, here's that update.

Comment: The error suggests that `$('g')[cityIndex]` is not a jQuery Object

Comment: @Twisty that did the trick, thanks!